# Why PHP in_array function always returns true

Tags: php, arrays

I've a problem with the `in_array` function.

This is my `array`: keys can be a mix of string or int like this example.

```
<?php

$array = array(
    "a" => true,
    "b" => true,
    "c" => true,
    "d" => true,
    0 => "Code",
    1 => "Time",
    2 => "Other"
);

var_dump($array);

if ( in_array("Test", $array) ) { echo "found"; }
```

This code print ALWAYS `found`.

Why?

Comment: [Type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php)

Answer (score 9):

Because you have `true` elements in your array and your "Test" string evaluates to true as well.

Try enabling the strict flag like this `in_array('Test', $array, true)` for a strict comparison.